# where can i find an uncompressed video recording from iPhone 3G/3GS/4

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'm experimenting with video processing and I'm looking for uncompressed video frames from iPhone. It is possible to record them since iOs 4.0 by dumping a buffer from api to the file..

Google didn't help..

Anybody? Where can I find such videos to download, or perhaps there is an app for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find what's not possible.

The iPhone 4 video camera can generate roughly 83 megabytes of uncompressed RGB data per second (1280 * 720 * 30 * 3).  The file system doesn't have that much write bandwidth by maybe over an order of magnitude difference, so you either have to rapidly compress the video data, skip frames, or only record a small portion of each frame.

Comment: Good point. but if I could skip frames & rapidly compress like 5-10 frames into png or pcx a second?